# PHP/Laravel: How deep copy a object and change value

Tags: php, laravel, object

It is possible to clone an instantiated object and change some value and create a new object with these changed values but without changing the values of the original object.

I know I can perform a deep copy using the command `unserialize(serialize($swift))`, but I have not found any way to change the values.

**Source/Original:**

```
Swift_Mailer {#777
  -transport: Swift_SmtpTransport {#779
    -handlers: array:1 [
      "AUTH" => Swift_Transport_Esmtp_AuthHandler {#783
        -authenticators: array:5 [
          0 => Swift_Transport_Esmtp_Auth_CramMd5Authenticator {#784}
          1 => Swift_Transport_Esmtp_Auth_LoginAuthenticator {#785}
          2 => Swift_Transport_Esmtp_Auth_PlainAuthenticator {#786}
          3 => Swift_Transport_Esmtp_Auth_NTLMAuthenticator {#787}
          4 => Swift_Transport_Esmtp_Auth_XOAuth2Authenticator {#788}
        ]
        -username: "myname@domain.local"
        -password: "mypassword"
        -auth_mode: null
        -esmtpParams: []
      }
    ]
    -capabilities: []
    -params: array:8 [
      "protocol" => "ssl"
      "host" => "mail.domain.com"
      "port" => 465
      "timeout" => 30
      "blocking" => 1
      "tls" => false
      "type" => 1
      "stream_context_options" => []
    ]
```

**Changed:**

```
Swift_Mailer {#777
  -transport: ...
        ]
        -username: "myname@otherdomain.local"
        -password: "otherpassword"
        ...
      }
    ]
    -capabilities: []
    -params: array:8 [
      "protocol" => "tls"
      "host" => "mail.otherdomain.net"
      "port" => 888
      ...
    ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure which PHP version you are running, but [clone](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.cloning.php) comes to mind.
Note that objects within the objects etc might be an issue depending on if/how the `__clone` function is setup for the object.

Comment: You would just call the available setter methods on the new object. If you want to change non-publicaly available member variables you will have to do some "magic". But often times an object is designed to give you access to the things you are expected to have to access.

Comment: For change private properties have to use any magic with php reflection. But first think why really need to do that instead of create new object with new properties. Also use setter like @inquam said is best choice.